# GLSL - Uniform Buffer Object weird behaviour

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, uniform

I have noticed strange behaviour of uniform buffer object when I change the order of struct members (the struct in the shader is the same as struct in cpp). This is my source code (the working version):

CPP:

```
struct Matrices {
    // vec3, mat4 - glm library
    mat4 projectionMatrix; 
    mat4 viewMatrix;
    vec3 eyePosition;
};
```

GLSL:

```
layout (std140) uniform matrices {
    mat4 projectionMatrix;
    mat4 viewMatrix;
    vec3 eyePosition;
};
```

CPP ubo generation:

```
GLuint tmpUBO[2];
glGenBuffers(2, tmpUBO);
uniformBlocks["matrices"].bindingPoint = MATRICES_BINDING_POINT;
uniformBlocks["matrices"].ubo = tmpUBO[0];
glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, tmpUBO[0]);
glBufferData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, sizeof(Matrices), &matrices, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0);
```

CPP updating ubo data:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, uniformBlocks["matrices"].ubo);
GLvoid *p = 
    glMapBufferRange(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(Matrices), 
    GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_INVALIDATE_RANGE_BIT);
memcpy(p, &matrices, sizeof(Matrices));
glUnmapBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER);
glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0);
```

CPP binding ubo to linked and active shader:

```
GLuint bi = glGetUniformBlockIndex(handle, name);
glBindBufferBase(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, bindingPoint, ubo);
glUniformBlockBinding(handle, bi, bindingPoint);
```

This version is working totally fine, but when I change the order of struct members (in both glsl and cpp), for example:

```
struct Matrices {
    vec3 eyePosition;
    mat4 projectionMatrix; 
    mat4 viewMatrix;
}
```

one or both of the matrices is not updated when I move the camera or change the perspective.

Does anybody have any idea what is causing this?

Comment: what are the definitions of the vec3 and mat4 structs in cpp?

Comment: I am using glm library - it is compatible with glsl.

Comment: Might be different padding. What is `sizeof(Matrices)` for the second version?

Comment: The size is the same, I don't think padding should be a problem since these are all floats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer on this website http://www.opentk.com/node/2926. The problem was with alignment of struct variables in shader.

Comment: Yes, `mat4` must begin on a 4-machine unit boundary (the spec.'s fancy way of saying 16-byte). Review the rules for `std140`, having a `vec3` followed by a `mat4` isn't properly packed, there's implicitly a `float` sandwiched in-between the two things. The alternative would be to move the `vec3` to the end of the struct, it actually has to be aligned to a 16-byte boundary too, but if you place it directly after a `mat4`, that's automatic ;)